# Enabling Spatial Analyst extension in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, arcgis-license-manager

I am getting all the spatial analyst tools locked in my ArcGIS Pro. I know i have these in my license and i remember in ArcGIS Desktop there is an option to enable extension of Spatial analyst then you can use the tools. I am hoping the same behavior in ArcGIS Pro How ever i am **unable to find that extension enabling option**.

Is it different in ArcGIS Pro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS Pro Help has a page on [Enabling the Spatial Analyst extension](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/basics/enabling-the-spatial-analyst-extension.htm):

> Once the software is installed, you need to enable the extension
>   before you can work with it. ArcGIS Pro requires that an administrator
>   of an organization assign software licenses and extensions. Once you
>   have been assigned the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension, you gain
>   access to the tools.